# what are some good ways to populate a rails development database with fake data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am moving away from fixtures and populate and looking for some alternative tools to populate my development database with fake data.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

[factory_girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/tree/master) is my personal favorite. Nice syntax, flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Forgery](http://github.com/sevenwire/forgery/tree/master)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few railscasts about this topic:

[126 Populating a database](http://railscasts.com/episodes/126-populating-a-database)

[158 Factories not Fixtures](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures)